How can I get GOOGLEFINANCE to retrieve a ticker's high and low price data for a 15 minute period?
I would like to retrieve a ticker's High and Low prices for a 15 minute period using the GOOGLEFINANCE function but am unable to get to.
Can anyone provide a formula?

Unfortunately, GOOGLEFINANCE does not support 15-minute intervals. 
Supported values are daily or weekly.


https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281

